# Access syntax error issues

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

My problem is that I would like to realize a query, and it throws syntax error. I find no ways to do this in the query designer, I think, I can only do it by directly writing sql codes.

My code is:

```
select distinct Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No], 
    atabla.[Outgoing date] as ext1date, 
from (Daily_Output20151013
inner join (select Daily_Output20151013.[Lot no] from (Daily_Output20151013.[Outgoing date] 
where Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern] = 'a') as atabla 
on Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No] = atabla.[Lot No])
```

These are existing tables and records, except atabla which is going to be the output table.

The error message is: "Syntax error in FROM clause".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra `(` after Daily_Output20151013. Removed it. This should work.

```
select distinct Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No], 
atabla.[Outgoing date] as ext1date
from (Daily_Output20151013
inner join (select [Lot no], [Outgoing date]
            from Daily_Output20151013
            where Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern] = 'a') as atabla 
on Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No] = atabla.[Lot No])
```

Comment: Thank you, but it throws: "Select contains an occupied or invalid word or argument"

Comment: the dervied table should use `Daily_Output20151013` table if i am correct. did you try the latest version of the answer?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. The table's name is Daily_Output20151013. I tried it, but it failed.

Comment: If there is any more information that needed, please report it, and I am going to write it here.

Comment: i just modified it. the derived table isn't selecting the [Outgoing date] column. I added it. try this.

Comment: I am sorry, but it still throws the same exception.

Comment: Thank you, your code almost worked, but somehow that comma doesn't need there before the "from" in line 2. I don't really know why, but it doesn't throw error this way and works properly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It throws error because of the comma before the from in line 2

The correct code is:

```
select distinct Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No], 
atabla.[Outgoing date] as ext1date 
from Daily_Output20151013
inner join (select [Lot no], [Outgoing date]
        from Daily_Output20151013
        where Daily_Output20151013.[Process Pattern] = 'a') as atabla 
on Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No] = atabla.[Lot No]
```